# Getting the size of each dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

Let's say I want to write a function to "unpack" (store or log, perhaps) a multidimensional array using nested loops. The concept is simple enough, provided I'm able to determine, in the case of a 3D array, the length, width and height of the array.

In Objective-C, is there some way to, after being passed a multidimensional array of unknown size as a method argument, determine what those dimension sizes are? Then it'd be a simple matter of using, as stated, nested for loops.

Comment: `NSArray` or C array, or something else?

Comment: @JoshCaswell let's go with an NSArray. If there exists functionality in C to accomplish this, I could go with either Objc or a standard C array. We can assume the array is immutable.

Comment: Well, `NSArray` will tell you its [`count`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/count), and the inner `NSArray`s can do likewise. I'm not sure what else you'd need. Is there some deeper problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray is inherently one dimensional, a vector if you like, and as noted by John it has a count property. To simulate a multidimensional array you could of course have a `NSArray *rows` that contains a number of `NSAarray *columnElement` and so forth. This is not really a multi diensional array and more like a tree type structure but you could sort of call it an array. But I do not think that is what you are asking.

I think you are thinking of a C style buffer of memory traversed by pointer references. This is also inherently a one dimensional structure as memeory adressing is one dimensional. In many cases such a buffer can be viewed as 2 or more dimensional in such way that you say every 50 bytes is a row, so position 0 is row 1 col 1, position 49 is row 1 col 50 and position 50 is row 2 col 1 etc.

In this case as it is you as the designer who have defined this interpretation of the buffer as a two-dimensional array there cannot be a way to derive the structure from the buffer alone. Either you have to store the arrangement of the buffer as metadata in other variables or impose some form of delimeter characters in the buffer, e.g. newline for new row. and comma for new column element or similar (but then it is no longer an array in my opinion it is a file format, here a csv file).